# Can Go capture a click event in an HTML document it is serving?

Tags: html, go, onclick

I am writing a program for managing an inventory. It serves up html based on records from a postresql database, or writes to the database using html forms.

Different functions (adding records, searching, etc.) are accessible using `<a></a>` tags or form submits, which in turn call functions using `http.HandleFunc()`, functions then generate queries, parse results and render these to html templates.

The search function renders query results to an html table. To keep the search results page ideally usable and uncluttered I intent to provide only the most relevant information there.  However, since there are many more details stored in the database, I need a way to access that information too. In order to do that I wanted to have each table row clickable, displaying the details of the selected record in a status area at the bottom or side of the page for instance.

I could try to follow the pattern that works for running the other functions, that is use `<a></a>` tags and `http.HandleFunc()` to render new content but this isn't exactly what I want for a couple of reasons.

First: There should be no need to navigate away from the search result page to view the additional details; there are not so many details that a single record's full data should not be able to be rendered on the same page as the search results.

Second: I want the whole row clickable, not merely the text within a table cell, which is what the `<a></a>` tags get me.

Using the id returned from the database in an attribute, as in `<div id="search-result-row-id-{{.ID}}"></div>` I am able to work with individual records but I have yet to find a way to then capture a click in Go.

Before I run off and write this in javascript, does anyone know of a way to do this strictly in Go? I am not particularly adverse to using the tried-and-true js methods but I am curious to see if it could be done without it.

Comment: Go cannot do this. Your sample code is part of Go's template package which parses and executes the template before sending the HTML to the client. Go knows nothing about the client after it serves its response, so you'd have to do this in JS.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Go, you need to write the correct html and javascript for the client.

Comment: The entire concept you have about how things work in the web has "room for improvents" as they say. In short: HTML is rendered in a browser, that's also where events happen. The browser and your (Go) HTML server are two entirely different processes. In the browser you may catch click events using JavaScript (but not with Go), and send an AJAX request back to your server, which then usually is programmed (by you) to respond with some suitable JSON. To make these AJAX things easier, have a look at the jQuery library (to name just one).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> does anyone know of a way to do this strictly in Go?

As others have indicated in the comments, no, Go cannot capture the event in the browser.

For that you will need to use some JavaScript to send to the server (where Go runs) the web request for more information.

You could also push all the required information to the browser when you first serve the page and hide/show it based on CSS/JavaScript event but again, that's just regular web development and nothing to do with Go.

Comment: Thanks. Answer accepted. I assumed that would be the case.